# VPN connect using Java

Tags: java, vpn, cisco

Is there a way to connect and disconnect VPN in Forticlient programmatically?

I see that with Cisco VPN Client, there are options such as using the APIs they provide or executing connectivity commands from my Java code. Views and opinions on these ways of connecting to VPN are also most welcome.

I am looking for such options or any other that is possible, with Forticlient software.

Any directions from here would be of great help.

*My trial so far :*

```
private static final String COMMAND = "C:/Program Files/Cisco/Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client/vpncli"; 

private ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ(10); 

public void connectToVPNViaCLI(String server, String uname, String pwd) 
{ 
    try { 
          String command = COMMAND + " connect " + server; 
          Spawn sp = exp.spawn(command); 
          sp.expect("Username: "); 
          sp.send(uname + "\n"); 
          sp.expect("Password: "); 
          sp.send(pwd + "\n"); 
          sp.expect("accept? [y/n]: "); 
          sp.send("y" + "\n"); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          LOGGER.severe(e.getMessage()); 
        }
}
```

Comment: @tom I tried this piece of code to run the VPN connectivity command. But I am facing issues here. I get an IO exception at the line where I am trying to expect a "Password" prompt and send() the "pwd" value. Also, APIs of both Forticlient and Cisco seem to be available in their dll(vpnapi.dll for Cisco and fccomintdll.dll for Forticlient). So I am left with two ways as of now. One, is to get the reference of these dll files and access the available methods. Second, to execute commands as I had done in my above code. If there are other options too, then please suggest.

Comment: did you find the solution .if yes please post the answer

Comment: am also facing the same issue. I couldn't find a solution for this